# Computing rank in respective histories

Tags: r, distribution, rank

I'd like to calculate the rank of the price of some fruits compared to their previous daily prices.

In the last few days the prices were in the following `past.csv`.

```
"Product","3/06/2018","3/05/2018","3/04/2018","3/03/2018"
"Apple",1.3,1.2,1.2,1.3
"Orange",1.3,1.4,1.6,1.7
"Kiwi",0.8,0.9,1.0,1.2
"Banana",0.6,0.8,0.9,1.0
```

The current prices are in the following `current.csv`.

```
"Day","Product","Price"
"3/07/2018","Apple",1.4
"3/07/2018","Orange",1.5
"3/07/2018","Kiwi",1.1
"3/07/2018","Banana",0.7
```

After reading the two CSV files, I copy the current prices

```
past.df <- read.csv(file="past.csv", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
current.df <- read.csv(file="current.csv", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
past.df$"Price" <- current.df$"Price"[match(past.df$"Product", current.df$"Product")]
```

calculate the ECDF on the relevant subset

```
before.last.col <- ncol(past.df) - 1
past.df$"Rank" <- ecdf(past.df[,2:before.last.col])(current$"Price")
```

and then copy back

```
current.df$"Rank" <- past.df$"Rank"[match(current.df$"Product", past.df$"Product")]
```

I'm expecting the column c(1.0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.25).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you define `past.df$"Rank"`. Basically you see `ecdf` as a multivariate empirical cdf, while it's just univariate. For this reason, we need to apply `ecdf` row by row. For instance,

```
past.df$"Rank" <- sapply(1:nrow(past.df), function(x) 
  ecdf(unlist(past.df[x, 2:before.last.col]))(current.df$"Price"[x]))
```

which leads to

```
current.df$"Rank"
# [1] 1.00 0.50 0.75 0.25
```